# Makefile and qt5: link qt5 with debugging symbols

Tags: c++, makefile, gdb, qt5

How can I link a Qt5 application with the Qt5 debugging symbols? I don't use qmake or CMake, but a custom-made Makefile.

I have installed the `qtbase5-dbg` package (Ubuntu/apt-get), and look at the files installed by it:

```
$ dpkg-query -L qtbase5-dbg
/.
/usr
/usr/lib
/usr/lib/debug
/usr/lib/debug/.build-id
/usr/lib/debug/.build-id/41
/usr/lib/debug/.build-id/41/3bc01e071e9ab5017efcbf7bb32141ee00d252.debug
/usr/lib/debug/.build-id/e0
/usr/lib/debug/.build-id/e0/2503fd33b4c52e37b27b6aa13ef11e986d27ba.debug
/usr/lib/debug/.build-id/73
/usr/lib/debug/.build-id/73/802b8d5cf3e3b3678e344bff64cbf779a33753.debug
/usr/lib/debug/.build-id/04
/usr/lib/debug/.build-id/04/e02531112cfb2f2b8ca6eb152a6c4ae4f33add.debug
/usr/lib/debug/.build-id/04/192a6729ab4790403739d97d46e2ac1f3203d7.debug

# Bunch of other similar files 

/usr/lib/debug/.build-id/e7/e69cb1ea874ede7a24216ef54aa9458e5b8ef0.debug
/usr/lib/debug/.build-id/ff
/usr/lib/debug/.build-id/ff/abd7ced1a66a9bde6b0355267e0ed38e83fa5b.debug
/usr/lib/debug/.build-id/53
/usr/lib/debug/.build-id/53/070dadaef9fa7fb45640b17d77ee3aeeac7b13.debug
/usr/lib/debug/.build-id/49
/usr/lib/debug/.build-id/49/7b2ab307020f81218ae77a749826793a074134.debug
/usr/share
/usr/share/doc
/usr/share/doc/qtbase5-dbg
/usr/share/doc/qtbase5-dbg/copyright
/usr/share/doc/qtbase5-dbg/LGPL_EXCEPTION.txt
/usr/share/doc/qtbase5-dbg/changelog.Debian.gz
```

So, there is no explicit `.so` library with debugging symbols, but other files instead.

Could anyone please give me a sample `g++` line with debugging symbols for Qt5 libraries enabled (for `gdb` debugging)?

Answer (score 0):

The Qt5 debugging symbols was correctly found by `gdb` inside the `/usr/lib/debug/.build-id` folder. I did just need to wait the Qt's dynamic libraries are loaded before using them:

```
$ gdb ./myapp
(gdb) start # (1)
(gdb) break any_Qt's_function
```

`start` runs the executable with a breakpoint set in `main`. So, when the program reachs `main`, `gdb` breaks, and you can then set new breakpoints in `Qt`'s functions because the dynamic libraries, and their debugging files, are, at last, loaded.